# Adjusting size of Bootstrap 3 form controls

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r9xpena2/) for full code example.

A few things that are triggering my OCD:

- Email & password inputs feel small compared to the "Sign up" button; how do I make them a little bigger, so that they're the same size as this button?
- By the same token, how do I make the green "Sign up" button the same width as the email/password inputs?
- The text under the password input (that starts "*Use at least...*") should be tiny; same size as the checkbox underneath it. I tried applying a `.tiny-text` class but that doesn't seem to work.

The `.tiny-text` class:

```
.tiny-text {
    font-size: x-small;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Use the `input-lg` class to make the inputs taller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `form-control` class to the button to make it as wide as the text inputs then and add some extra CSS to fix the height:

```
.form-control[type='email'],
.form-control[type='password'],
.btn.form-control {
    height: 50px;
}
```

And your CSS selector for `tiny-text` isn't specific enough so it was not being used. Try this:

```
.jumbotron p.tiny-text {
    font-size: x-small;
}
```

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nxda9fm8/